# How can I generate an Id for a new custom field (Ex: <Field ID="{5744d18c-305e-4632-8bd1-09d134f4830d}" )?

Tags: custom, content

For Example: this is the custom field definition in Element .xml file.

```
<Field ID="{5744d18c-305e-4632-8bd1-09d134f4830d}" 
    Type="Note" 
    Name="PatientName" 
    DisplayName="Patient Name" 
    Group="A Custom Group">
</Field>
```

My concern is: how can I generate a new FieldID if I need to provision a new field? Also how can I get the FieldRef reference to be used in a Content Type definition?

Answer (score 5):

You can always generate new GUIDs using [Online GUID generator](http://www.guidgenerator.com/) or using Visual Studio

This is how you can provision your field and use it in a Content Type using `FieldId` and `FieldRef`. Follow the sample `elements.xml` below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">

<Field ID="{5744d18c-305e-4632-8bd1-09d134f4830d}" 
    Type="Note" 
    Name="PatientName" 
    DisplayName="Patient Name" 
    Group="A Custom Group">
</Field>

<ContentType ID="0x0101000728167cd9c94899925ba69c4af6743e"
               Name="Financial Document"
               Group="Financial Content Types"
               Description="Base financial content type"
               Version="0">
    <FieldRefs>
      <!--  Built-in Title field -->
      <FieldRef ID="{5744d18c-305e-4632-8bd1-09d134f4830d}" Name="PatientName" DisplayName="Patient Name" Required="TRUE" Sealed="TRUE"/>
    </FieldRefs>
</ContentType>



</Elements>
```